# Как организовать систему онлайн пользователей в клиент-серверном приложении C#

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, online

Нужно чтобы пользователи видели кто из других пользователей онлайн.
Как лучше реализовать проверку на то пользователь онлайн или нет?
Как это лучше проверить по TCP/IP?